# How to add the element id in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add element id for every react element, but I am not able to add element id to

```
React.createElement(
    {
        option:{this.state}
        className:'form-control'
        value:'sample'
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

React createElement has the below syntax (may be one of the syntax)

```
React.createElement(elementType, props/attributes, value);
```

For Example

```
React.createElement('li', {id:'list_one'}, 'List one');
```

Above example creates below element

```
<li id="list_one">List one</li>
```

However since second parameter is a prop aswell, Its better to pass Id as a prop rather than fixing it to something as above. By Passing props, we can control Id's of elements.